# How to get child element when query by parent key, AngularFire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning Firebase + AngularFire2.

My DB in firebase is like .

[image]

Whe I try to get child of courses > ncjkdhjjd8ejd. by using

```
let ll = (_angularFire.list("courses/ncjkdhjjd8ejd"));

ll.subscribe(
  (val) => console.log(val)
)
```

I am getting :

[image]

How can I get it in a single json object, not 3 arrays.

I only want values in json structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an AngularFire2 [`object` observable](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md) instead:

```ts
let course = _angularFire.object("courses/ncjkdhjjd8ejd");
course.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Superb. Thanks a lot sir.